# problem about a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(a_n)_{n\geq2}$ be a sequence defined as
>   $$
> a_2=1,\qquad a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}a_n.
> $$
>   Show that
>   $$
> a_n=\frac{n}{2(n-1)},\quad\forall n\geq2
> $$
>   and determine $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n$.

I cannot show that $a_n$ is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{n}{n-1}$. Some helps?

Thank You

Comment: Do you know proof by induction? Also note that $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try induction.

First of all, notice that if $n=2$, then
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{n}{n-1}=1=a_1$$
Which proves that the explicit formula holds for $a_1$. Then suppose that for some $k$, the formula holds. Then
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2}\frac{k}{k-1}$$
and so, using the recursive definition,
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}a_k$$
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(k+1)(k-1)}{k^2}\frac{k}{k-1}$$
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{k+1}{k}$$
$$a_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1)-1}$$
and so $a_{k+1}$ also follows the formula.

Let $S_k$ be the statement
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2}\frac{k}{k-1}$$
We have proven $S_2$ and $S_k\implies S_{k+1}$, so
$$S_2\implies S_3\implies S_4\implies ...$$
or, in other words, $S_k$ is true for all $k\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_{n}=\frac{(n-1)a_n}{n}$.

Thus, $b_{n+1}=b_n$ and since $b_2=\frac{2-1}{2}a_2=\frac{1}{2}$, we are done!

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1}=(1-\frac{1}{n^2})a_n=(1-\frac{1}{n^2})(1-\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}) a_{n-1}=\prod_{k=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{k^2}) $ where the last step follows from the fact that $a_2=1$. Now $\frac{k^2-1}{k^2}=\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$, so writing down the first few terms you'll convince yourself that everything cancels except $\frac{1}{2}$ at the beginning and $\frac{n}{n-1}$ at the end obtaining the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can substitute the common term formula into the difference equation to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$. Write the recursion formula as
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}.
$$
From here we have that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\big(\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}\big)\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}.
$$
Applying this repeatedly we arrive at
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac{a_2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n},
$$
which is the desired conclusion.