# Limit of a recursive sequence when the law explicitly depends also on $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

If I have to find the limit of a recursive sequence I know I can use the following theorem:
Let $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, where $f$ is a continuos function. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ then $l=f(l).$
For example:
$$\begin{cases}a_0=0;\\ a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n})\end{cases}$$
Using the theorem I would have: $l=\frac{1}{2}(l+\frac{1}{l})\iff l=\pm 1$.

**My problem:** if I have a recursive sequence, where in the recursive law also a function of $n$ appears how can I apply the theorem?
To be more clear I will do an example:
$$\begin{cases}a_2=1;\\ a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}a_n\end{cases}$$
In this case if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}a_n\iff l=l.$ But $l=l$ is always true and so I have not obtained any information about the limit.

So:

> 1)Have I committed any mistakes in this last procedure and in this case how can I proceed?
> 2)If not the only possibility to determine the limit is to obtain the explicit definition of $a_n$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414472/42969

Comment: I don't want the solution of the problem, my questions are more general...this link does not help me for my doubts

Comment: You've correctly applied the limit operator to both sides; it just didn't give you any information, as you pointed out. In this particular example, look for a pattern among the first several $a_n$; once you find it, you should be able to prove it by induction on $n$ and thereby calculate the limit. PS: You might want to change the value of $a_0$ in your initial example, since it forces $a_1$ already to be undefined.

Comment: @GregMartin do you mean that in this case the only possibility is to determine the explicit expression of $a_n$?

Comment: I won't say "only possibility"—there are always lots of possible strategies. I'm just (a) agreeing with you that the strategy you tried didn't solve the problem and (b) suggesting another strategy that I believe does solve the problem.

Comment: Looking for fixed points of $f$ is a technique for figuring out possible limits for $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$. But it is not the only means to do so. And as you've noticed, it is far from fullproof. It is not universally applicable. In addition to $f$ also depending on $n$, it could be that $f$ has multiple fixed points, not just one. And even when $f$ has a single fixed point, that does not guarantee that $a_n$ converges to it. In this case, this method failed. That means it is time to try something else.

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone!